# Dynamically invoke property file to soapui using ANT

Tags: ant, soapui

I setup jenkins job to trigger SoapUI API automation suite using Apache ANT.
I want that before running the suite, External property file should be call first and load properties.

Build.xml :

```
<project name="soapUI Nightly Build" default="testreport" basedir=".">

<target  name ="soapui">    
<exec dir="." executable="C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SoftwareRequired/SoapUI/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/testrunner.bat">
<arg line="-j -f 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2' 'C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SOAP_Script/VisitorSearchAPI-soapui-project.xml'"/>
</exec>
</target>

<target name ="testreport" depends ="soapui">
<junitreport todir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2">
    <fileset dir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2">
         <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <report todir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2/HTML"
            styledir="C:/apache-ant-1.9.6-bin/apache-ant-1.9.6/etc"
            format="noframes">

    </report>
</junitreport>  
</target>

</project>
```

Property file path :

```
C:\IntegerationAPI\APIPackage\Property_Files\VisitorSearchProperties.Properties
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I don't follow, but can you not use the Ant [propertyfile task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html)?

Comment: where do you need to load it? in the `build.xml`? or soapui project / suite?

Comment: What's the problem with just using the `<property>` task at the beginning of your script? You said you want it to be loaded dynamically but you didn't indicate what part of it needs to be dynamic, or in what way. All of the other file paths in your script are hard coded, so why isn't it a similar problem with them?

Comment: I don't know which is the right way do to as i am new to this....i understand this can be in two ways. This is good whenever soapui runs it should first loads the properties from external file. This way when ANT invoke the soapui then it automatically run with updated properties. Right?

Comment: @rAJ, At what level do you need to load the properties to soapui project? to project level? or any particular suite level?

Comment: @Rao at project level.

Comment: @rAJ, what is the project name?

Comment: @Rao VisitorSearch_API

Comment: @rAJ, thanks for the input. Please try the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is pass jvm argument as below to the test runner command.

To load the external property file at project level
-Dsoapui.properties.=

To load the external property file at test suite level
-Dsoapui.properties.=

Coming to your case, add below to your existing testrunner command:

```
-Dsoapui.properties.VisitorSearch_API=C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/Property_Files/VisitorSearchProperties.Properties
```

You could change your `soapui` target as below, note the change in start of `arg` element.

```
<target  name ="soapui">    
    <exec dir="C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SoftwareRequired/SoapUI/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin" executable="testrunner.bat">
        <arg line="-Dsoapui.properties.VisitorSearch_API=C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/Property_Files/VisitorSearchProperties.Properties -j -f 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2' 'C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SOAP_Script/VisitorSearchAPI-soapui-project.xml'"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: `<exec dir="." executable="C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SoftwareRequired/SoapUI/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/testrunner.bat">
<arg line="-Dsoapui.properties.VisitorSearch_API=C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/Property_Files/VisitorSearchProperties.Properties -j -f 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2' 'C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SOAP_Script/VisitorSearchAPI-soapui-project.xml'"/>
</exec>`   Still getting the same result. No effect in result due to new parameters. My project xml have the properties already. It is not overriding the existing parameters.

Comment: Can you first try it on command line using testrunner utility? By the way, how do know it is overriding or not? are you logging any where? would you mind showing log?

Comment: I run this `C:\IntegerationAPI\APIPackage\SoftwareRequiC:\Windows\system32>C:\IntegerationAPI\APIPackage\SoftwareRequired\SoapUI\SoapUI
-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat -j -f 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Intege
rationAPI-2' 'C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SOAP_Script/VersionInformation-soapu
i-project.xml'"` and output is `Missing SoapUI project file..`. The output html report file is always be the same that's why i am saying it is not taking new properties and using the old one which is present in xml file.

Comment: @rAJ, your command is incorrect. Go to directory `SOAPUI_HOME/bin`; use actual path. And run `testrunner.bat -Dsoapui.properties.VisitorSearch_API=C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/Property_Files/VisitorSearchProperties.Properties -j -f "C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/Intege rationAPI-2" C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SOAP_Script/VersionInformatio‌​n-soapu i-project.xml`

Comment: Still the message is same:-
`C:\IntegerationAPI\APIPackage\SoftwareRequired\SoapUI\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin>C:\Intege
rationAPI\APIPackage\SoftwareRequired\SoapUI\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat -j
-f 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2' 'C:/Integeration
API/APIPackage/SOAP_Script/VersionInformation-soapui-project.xml'"`

Comment: Also used this : `C:\IntegerationAPI\APIPackage\SoftwareRequired\SoapUI\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin>testrunner.bat -j -f 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/IntegerationAPI-2' 'C:/IntegerationAPI/APIPackage/SOAP_Script/VersionInformation-soapui-project.xml'"`

Comment: You are not following what is suggested. Try exactly what is provided earlier.